# NLP (Natural Language processing), Machine Learning,deep Learning

Tags: google-cloud-nl

i am developing an ASR system for my local kashmiri language and had Already had done some work collected some data and trained a CNN model on it with not so good accuracy but now i want to change the Strategy i want to do this work on phoneme level can any buddy suggest me the way to do it please.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please consider adding google-cloud-speech tag to your question, since this is primarily a speech recognition question.